# What happens to armor a marine has gained during a campaign when he dies?

Tags: doom

**Preface**

This question is about Doom: The Boardgame. I have translated the rules and items etc. from my native tongue to english to the best of my knowledge, so please be gentle.

**The Question**

Suppose you are playing a campaign. A marine has found a piece of armor in scenario I and did not die in that one afterwards. So he starts with armor +1 in scenario II. Now the question is: What happens, if the marine dies (kill) in scenario II. Does he respawn with armor +0 or +1 ? Does it make a difference when he has bought the armor using killpoints instead of finding it in one scenario ?

**My interpretation**

The combination of

*A killed marine respawns with the initial amount of armor and health. (rulebook)*

and

*A marine starts a scenario with the armor and health of the previous scenario (campaign book)*

has lead me to the conclusion, that if e.g. Martin the marine starts scenario II with armor 2+1 and health 4 (of maximum 9) and he dies within the scenario, the he respawns with armor 2+1 and health 4 (while maximum remains 9 of course).

However, this interpretation is both counterintuitive (regarding health) and (maybe) a balance issue (regarding **found** armor).

Comment: Please retag using the tag "doom" which seems not be present on the board (yet). With rep < 150 I am not allowed to create that tag on my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a player of the Doom board game, but I'm a player of many other board games and the Doom computer game and therefore think I can make a fair interpretation as to what the rulebook and campaign book rules might mean together.

I think rule 1 (A killed marine...) means that at any time the marine is killed **during** a scenario he will respawn with the default (as in without any items and bonuses) armour and health.

The second rule (A marine starts a scenario...) in my opinion is not contrary to that because it refers to the **beginning** of a scenario.

If a marine is killed **during** the scenario then rule 1 applies and rule 2 does not, if it is the **beginning** of the scenario rule 2 applies. This seems to match with the Doom computer game, if you finish a level you can take the armour and life to the next level, however if you are killed during a level you respawn with the default armour (0 I believe) and the default health (100 I believe) at the beginning of the level.

Comment: thank you. I did not play the computer game, but I always got the feeling that they try to mimic it as best as possible with the board game. So the rules within the computer game are indeed a strong indicator.